# Scrolling jumpy, scroll speed too fast, mouse acceleration weird

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics, scrolling

I'm currently switching from windows to ubuntu, and there are some very annoying things that just kill the whole experience.

1. if you use the touchpad, you scroll at lightspeed. I tried some scripts out, from various different answers but nothing worked.
   Then I set the firefox setting min scroll to 1 (from 5) but its still wayy too fast.
   It also is very "jumpy". On windows, if you give the touchpad a scroll, it just keeps scrolling, very smooth and very predictable. But here its just like zack! and you're at the bottom of the webpage.
2. The mouse acceleration when using a touchpad is... weird. It just feels off, and is way too slow and way too fast at times. I wanna have the old mouse acceleration from windows, but I don't know what thing it uses. (I tried: Default, Flat, Adaptive all are bad)

So my question is: What mouse acceleration does windows use, and how to get it in Ubuntu.
Also: How do I fix the lightspeed touchpad?

I feel like they are all very related, and might be able to get fixed in one go, like a fix-touchpad package, and so giving more information is more helpful. I know that usually you should post one question in one post.

Also: When using my G502 Logitech Mouse everything is fine and good as usual. My Laptop is the Lenovo Yoga 12.

Ubuntu Version: 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Did you try to tune mouse and touchpad speed in settings?

Comment: yeah, I did. The problem is that it seemingly randomly goes faster or slower than I would expect/anticipate.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: It should be wise to actually finish "switching from linux to ubuntu", whatever that means, and then see what heppens. :~)

Comment: windows to ubuntu xD
Edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently moved from Xubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 and surprisingly the scrolling experience is way much worse in the newer (and most popular) Ubuntu 22.04 than Xubuntu 20.04. This is a surprise since scrolling is such a basic feature that one expects (in 2022/2023) it to work perfectly out of the box, but it is not the case...

That said, I found out that starting a session with Xorg instead of the default (Wayland?) makes the scrolling in most of the apps (not all) to work much much better. To login with Xorg you have first to log out and then click on the engine on the bottom right of the screen:

[image]

and select Xorg. For me this fixed the jumpyness and the acceleration, as well as the inertial scroll now available in some apps (not all).

Comment: I'm already using Xorg, which fixed this kind of weird behavior when using a mouse. That said, the scrolling on my touchpad is still lightspeed, and not smooth (I want it to be, that I make a movement, and then it just keeps scrolling and then kinda fades out, the motion is comparable to a rusty fidget spinner that easily gets slower). Any advice? Edit: "Lightspeed" might be a *slight* exaggeration .